# From as partial view in layout page. MVC 5

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a `Partial View` in my `Layout page` which contain a Form. The partial view open as `popup`. After submitting form I have to return back to the current page with opened popup and a success message should appear there but I am not able to return back to the right view.

**My Layout Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title || Midas WebSite</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        /* Superior Web Systems */
        function displayHideBox(boxNumber) {

            if (document.getElementById("LightBox" + boxNumber).style.display == "none") {
                $("#LightBox" + boxNumber).fadeIn();
                $("#grayBG").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $("#LightBox" + boxNumber).fadeOut();
                $("#grayBG").fadeOut();
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="grayBG" class="grayBox" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="LightBox1" class="box_content" style="display:none;">
        <div onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;" class="close">X</div>
     @Html.Action("ActionToBindPartialView", "ControllerName")
</div>

 @RenderBody()
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

**My Partial View**

```
<div id="divActions">
   // My Form Here

    @Ajax.ActionLink("Submit", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions
         {
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           UpdateTargetId = "divActions",
           OnSuccess = "onSucess()" 
         })

</div>
```

Now my action code which I have tried so far:

**1.**

```
// My Code

 return PartialView("MyPartialView");
```

**2**

```
// My Code

return PartialView("MyPartialView", MyModel);
```

**3**

```
// My Code

return View();
```

**4**

```
// My Code

return ParialView();
```

I am a beginner and not able to find what I am doing wrong. Please suggest what should I do to make this work.

Comment: I would like to help, but I did not understand your problem.

Comment: I have a link on layout page which will open a form in popup. That form is in partial view. When I submit my form on success it should display a success message. But I do not have much knowledge so I not able to achieve this and I need help.

Comment: And what are you currently achieving?

Comment: My code is directly redirecting me to partial view. "MyAppURL/ControllerName/PartialView"

Comment: and some trials also redirecting to "My Action Name"

Comment: Aren't you missing the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" file?

Comment: Almost sure that you have a script issue :(, maybe a file missing, wrong order or even another snippet causing the error. Post your _Layout.cshtml code and the Partil View code. And check your browser Developer Tools for warnings and/or errors :)

Comment: ok I am updating the qestion

Comment: see my layout page content.

Comment: Not yet. Check if the bundles has been rendered correctly. View the source of your page and check for misplaced scripts.

Comment: Ok, I will check again.

Comment: I added  "<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>" to my layout page but still no luck.

Comment: Let me do an example for you. One second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say what you are doing wrong, due to the limited workspace that we have to discuss the problem. However here is a working example that may help you, please follow each step:

1. Bundles

   ```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
       .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        .Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
   ```
2. HomeController

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View();
   }

   public PartialViewResult GetPartial()
   {
       return PartialView("_MyPartial");
   }
   ```
3. Index.cshtml

   ```
   <h2>Index</h2>

   <div id="divActions">
       @Ajax.ActionLink("Submit", "GetPartial", "Home", new AjaxOptions
        {
          HttpMethod = "POST",
          UpdateTargetId = "divActions",
          OnSuccess="onSuccess()"
        })
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       function onSuccess()
       {
           alert("Success!");
       }
   </script>
   ```
4. _MyPartial.cshtml

   ```
    <h2>_MyPartial</h2>
   ```
5. _Layout.cshtml

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
      <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
   </head>
   <body>
       @RenderBody()

       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
6. To confirm the rendered scripts in the page source (in the browser):

   ```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
   ```

As you can see, there is nothing hard about it. You just need to follow the steps above.

I hope it helps.

**Hint**: check for other scripts errors, maybe your custom code to show the popup is causing a error. Double check if you are rendering javascript inside the partial view. Consider extract it to the regular view.

Comment: thank for your help and time, but according to my requirement partial view (containing my form) must be placed on _Layout.cshtml and after submitting the form I have to return back on it. (no matter on which child page I am it should return on that page and partial view should appear.)   :(

Comment: now I am replacing JQuery related code in my application with your code and will update you accordingly .. hope this will work .. thanks again :)

Comment: Ok, but you said that the problem was when you click do show the partial. And not when you submit the form. Also, you can move the code to the layout page without any problem. I strongly suggest to start from the code above and improve with your custom code/logic in small steps, so you can easily isolate the problem.

Comment: may be I was not able to explain my requirement properly. The partial view in on layout page. Now I have managed this situation by redirection to Request.Url to show desired view "(return RedirectToAction("../" + url);)" and with help of session and jQuery the popup is also displaying. But now the issue is that if validation has failed then View is not tracking that because of "RedirectToAction". One issue has solved and now I am not able to handle validation. I am searching on web and will update here once it worked.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, now project is done and I get chance to mark your reply as answer :) ... I uninstalled jQuery package, removed all references, cleared browser cache, then implemented your solution and it worked :) .. thanks again.